# SVG for WPF from illustrator – URL?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, wpf

Has anyone got some fool-proof settings for exporting SVG files from illustrator for WPF environment dev buttons?

Specifically, I'm being told by the developers the icons with a gradient  are creating a URL reference within the doc, the syntax appears correct but it won't read the URL gradient reference or ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You'll want convert `svg` to `xaml` files.

SVGs always reference a gradient by url. Even though its internal . Unlike CSS where you can specify a linear gradient as a property. SVGs reference an ID to an internal gradient `fill="url(#Gradient)"`. You can't get around this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
      <radialGradient id="Gradient"
            cx="0.5" cy="0.5" r="0.5" fx="0.25" fy="0.25">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="red"/>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
      </radialGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect x="10" y="10" rx="15" ry="15" width="100" height="100"
        fill="url(#Gradient)" />
  <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" fill="transparent" />
</svg>
```

**.NET** doesn't support SVGs very well (.NET being the Windows language used in WFP). There is a tool [sharpvectors](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sharpvectors) which should aid in making an SVG compatible in in .NET/WFP applications. Converting **SVG** into Windows custom format **XAML**.

It should also provide a GUI to view the graphic in a Windows/WFP environment. Offering some assurance that'll work before handing it to a Dev.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't handle URL gradients, then don't use a gradient. Perhaps use a raster image of a gradient instead, or even a step blend, and contain it within a clipping mask.

I don't know how practical this will be but at least it won't use a URL gradient. Maybe ask your developer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to give the ShapeConverter a try. It handles gradients well. Just download the latest executable from the releases and run it: https://github.com/gomi42/ShapeConverter. The ShapeConverter converts Illustrator, Photoshop, EPS and SVG to XAML and gives you quite a lot of options about the output format.